# Include softlinked folders in unix "find"

Tags: unix, find, symlink

How can I tell unix "find" to include in it's recursive search a folder which is softlinked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-L .  This causes it to follow all symbolic (I assume this is what you mean by soft) links.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - I hadn't come across '`-L`' (or the opposite, '`-H`') before.  You can also use '`-follow`' to do the same job.  It can be built into expressions (it always evaluates to true), so you might be able to be more subtle with it that using '`-L`'.  However, I wouldn't worry about that subtlety too much - the '`-L`' is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

find some more information about unix find command at

http://scripterworld.blogspot.com/2009/07/unix-find-command-with-examples-and.html